# Error: Module does not support depends_on

Tags: azure, terraform

```
#Get existing subnet properties
module "subnet" {
  #source = "git::git@bitbucket.org:exium-c2/azure-registery.git/az-sub"
  source         = "C:\\Users\\harip\\azure-registery\\az-sub"
  subnet_prefix4 = var.subnet_prefix4
  subnet_prefix6 = var.subnet_prefix6
  rg             = var.rg-name
  location       = var.rg-location
  vnet-name      = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  routeipv4      = data.azurerm_route_table.routeipv4.id
  routeipv6      = data.azurerm_route_table.routeipv6.id
  mgmt-sg-id     = data.azurerm_network_security_group.sg.id
  nwu-sg-id      = data.azurerm_network_security_group.sg1.id


}
module "nics" {
  #source = "git::git@bitbucket.org:exium-c2/azure-registery.git/az-nic"
  source = "C:\\Users\\harip\\azure-registery\\az-nic"
  #nic-name    = var.nic-name
  rg-name     = var.rg-name
  rg-location = var.rg-location
  #count= "${length(var.subnetwork-subnetid)}"
  subnetwork-subnetid  = module.subnet.subnetwork-subnetid
  subnetwork6-subnetid = module.subnet.subnetwork6-subnetid
  depends_on = [ module.subnet.subnetwork,module.subnet.subnetwork6 ]

}
module "fpm" {
  #source = "git::git@bitbucket.org:exium-c2/azure-registery.git/az-compute-fpm"
  source = "C:\\Users\\harip\\azure-registery\\az-compute-fpm"
  #count       = "${length(var.nic1-id)}"
  vm-name     = var.vm-name
  size        = var.size
  user-name   = var.user-name
  rg-name     = var.rg-name
  rg-location = var.rg-location
  nic1-id     = module.nics.nic1-id
  nic2-id     = module.nics.nic2-id

}
```

Plan to create multiple instances and based subnets and nics  so plan to use module with "dependence on" function .
error:
Error: Module does not support depends on
Please help in this. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Terraform version:
terraform version
Terraform v0.13.3
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.41.0

Comment: Do you have any example code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: yes I have but don't know how to paste here

Comment: This is explained in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow/51145

Comment: You don't need `depends_on` as you are already referencing outputs of `subnet` module in second module through `module.subnet.subnetwork-subnetid`.

Comment: so how can I use depends on  block on above module

Comment: You don't need. Do you get any errors if you remove `depends_on = [ module.subnet.subnetwork,module.subnet.subnetwork6 ]`?

Comment: here in my local "module  subnet " is there in separate file and " module nics"  & "module fpm" are in another file

Comment: if I remove 
depends_on = [ module.subnet.subnetwork,module.subnet.subnetwork6 ]
i'm not getting any error.But plan to implement different files and plan to use way that I need 4 nics for One VM and one nic for another VM  this is what I'm plan to implement code on to get  my Infra.

Comment: Then, does it work or there are some other issues that you think require `depends_on` to solve?

Comment: Plan to create two VM's based on nics such way that one VM need 1 NIC and another VM need 4 NICS for now using my code i could able to creat one VM with 4 NICS.

Comment: I have added VM module as well in above code. Could please do suggest how to achieve the above.

Comment: Hi any suggestions on my above question..?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have any suggestion. I don't fully understand what you want to achieve. Hopefully, someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Need to create a multiple VM's with the above code
1. first VM with 4 NICS --achieved
2. Second VM need to be created with  1 NIC --need to be created